# Fire and forget request on aws lambda@edge

Tags: aws-lambda-edge

Is there a way to do a fire-and-forget request on aws lambda@edge ? we would like to log some information out of AWS from our lambda edge but we do not like to wait for the response, is there any way to be able to fire and forget calls from lambda@edge aws?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-cloudfront-trigger-events.html

Quoting:
The CloudFront events that can be used to trigger Lambda@Edge functions are the following:

Viewer request
"The function executes when CloudFront receives a request from a viewer, before it checks to see whether the requested object is in the CloudFront cache.

Origin request
The function executes only when CloudFront forwards a request to your origin. When the requested object is in the CloudFront cache, the function doesn't execute.

Origin response
The function executes after CloudFront receives a response from the origin and before it caches the object in the response. Note that the function executes even if an error is returned from the origin.

The function doesn't execute in the following cases:

When the requested file is in the CloudFront cache and is not expired.

When the response is generated from a function that was triggered by an origin request event."